# Twitter 401 Unauthorized -- OAuth Request Token

Tags: php, api, http, twitter, oauth

I am using `file_get_contents` in PHP to make HTTP requests to the Twitter API.
When trying to request a token, I get the error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
```

Here is my code

```
$appID = "MY-CONSUMER-ID";
$appSecret = "MY-CONSUMER-SECRET";

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";

$oauth = array(
    "oauth_nonce" => base64_encode(time()),        
    "oauth_callback" => "MY-URL",
    "oauth_signature_method" => "HMAC-SHA1",
    "oauth_timestamp" => time(),
    "oauth_consumer_key" => $appID,
    "oauth_version" => "1.0"
);

$token_string = "POST&" . rawurlencode($url) . "&" . rawurlencode(http_build_query($oauth));
$signing_key = rawurlencode($appSecret) . "&";
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $token_string, $signing_key, true));

$oauth["oauth_signature"] = $signature;

$header = array();
foreach ($oauth as $key => $value) { $header[] = rawurlencode($key) . "=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\""; }
$header = implode(", ", $header);
$header = "Authorization: OAuth " . $header;
echo $header;

$opts = array('http' => array(
    'method'  => "POST",
    'header'  => $header,
) );

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: When requesting oauth token, just skip the `oauth_callback` parameter, but leave it set in Twitter's online DEV APP settings environment. Ukuser32 is also right, to make your signature work, you need parameters in alphabetical order, use ksort to sort the array.

Answer (score 1):

You actually helped me and I'll help anyone else who reads this post.

The issue why this wasn't working was because the $oauth array must be in alphabetical order (see https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature). Thus when it is http_build_queried it was wrong.

However this helped me because my signature was passing an expected o_token when we don't at this point have one (I use this code for signing all requests) so `$signing_key = rawurlencode($appSecret) . "&";` helped fix my problem.